# How to add a new column (Python list) to a Postgresql table?

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a Python list `newcol` that I want to add to an existing Postgresql table. I have used the following code:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(host='***', database='***', user='***', password='***')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('ALTER TABLE %s ADD COLUMN %s text' % ('mytable', 'newcol'))
conn.commit()
```

This added the list `newcol` to my table, however the new column has no values in it. In python, when I print the the list in python, it is a populated list.

Also, the number of rows in the table and in the list I want to add are the same. I'm a little confused.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN ...` doesn't add values from list - it only add/create (empty) column. To add values to this column you need `UPDATE` - learn SQL.

Comment: @furas, woops, got a little confused when pulling it into Python. In SQL, I've manually added each line in the past. Is there a way to update the values and add the whole list?

Comment: You could use `for` loop to get element from list and execute `UPDATE` query.

Answer (score 2):

`ALTER TABLE` only changes table schema -- in your case it will create the new column and initialize it with empty (NULL) values.

To add list of values to this column you can do:
`UPDATE TABLE <table> SET ...` in a loop.